# QGIS Layout Atlas Settings for one Layer with different Geometries per Attribute

Tags: qgis, layouts, atlas

Scenario: I have a line layer with a column where there are two different details about the condition (Road, Path). A second column (Parcel) defines in which parcel this condition is located. f.e.:

| parcel | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 73463 | road |
| 73463 | path |
| 73464 | road |
| 73465 | path |
| 73465 | path |

Problem: I would like to create an atlas function in the layout that displays all roads and paths sorted by parcel that are located in the active parcel, if possible with a dynamic function in the legend text to describe the length of each line within the parcel.

Comment: Do you have a parcel layer that is being used as they Atlas layer? Or is the Atlas being controlled by the roads/paths layer?

Comment: In this scenario Atlas should be controlled by the "roads/path" Layer, but a separate parcel layer exists, in case this would be a feasible approach.

Comment: I had my answer mostly written before I saw your reply, see if that works :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this answer I have a **parcels** layer with a numeric attribute "parcel_id", and a **routes** layers with a numeric attribute "parcel_id" for its parent parcel, and a text attribute "condition" with 'path' or 'road' attributes.

The **parcels** layer is controlling the Atlas, using the "parcel_id" attribute as the page name.

To only display routes that are within the current parcel feature you need to set up rule based symbology which filters using the routes' parcel_id attribute and matches it to the Atlas feature id, which used the parcel's parcel_id attribute:

```
"parcel_id" = @atlas_featureid
```

Combine that with rules for setting up the symbology classes and you get the following:

[image]

Now when you scroll through pages in the Atlas it will filter just to the features within that parcel.

To configure the legend to display some smarts, use the Expression setting:

[image]

Use an `aggregate()` function to sum the lengths of all the routes, but filter it by the "parcel_id" (using the Atlas feature id) and the "condition" (using the symbol label):

```
@symbol_label || ' - ' || aggregate('routes', 'sum', $length, "condition" = @symbol_label AND "parcel_id" = @atlas_featureid)
```

[image]

Then you can edit the expression to make it read better:

```
@symbol_label || ' - Sum of length in parcel: ' || round(aggregate('routes', 'sum', $length, "condition" = @symbol_label AND "parcel_id" = @atlas_featureid )/1000,2) || 'km'
```

Then you get the follow for parcels 1 and 2:

Parcel 1:
[image]

Parcel 2:
[image]

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing your approach. Allthough I made the settings in the Atlas, my lines are not displayed after setting the combined rule from the picture. Is there any place i should be using the ""parcel_id" = @atlas_featureid" line? What could I have missend?

Comment: maybe i should add that in my scenario the lines are crossing parcels and i have intersected them with the parcel layer, to get a truthful allocation... but that should not be the issue. To prove that there are lines I've temporarely made an extra rule...
https://i.imgur.com/pOAGKZI.png

Comment: The field name I used is "parcel_id" but I see now you use "parcel", so use `"parcel" = @atlas_featureid` instead

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but where do I use: "parcel" = @atlas_featureid?
I wrote - "condition" = 'road' AND @atlas_featureid in ("parcel") - in the filtersettings but am a little lost where do i put the other rule...

Comment: Hey TeddyTedTed, thank you for your help so far, but I am just not getting any lines displayed with the rule. Do you stil have the project saved so i could dowload it and learn, where my mistake is?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You set this up as rule-based symbology for the routes layer (Right click layer in Table of Contents > Properties > Symbology > change drop down to Rule Based. Something I forgot to mention, they may not display until you actually switch on the Atlas in the layout view. This is because until the Atlas is switched on the $atlas_featureid will either be null or a nonsensical value which won't match your parcel_ids.

Comment: No Problem TeddyTedTed. Unfortunately It is stil not working... I have prepared a geopackage with hopefully the exact setting. Maybe you could take a look what I am missing? Could it be, that in my QGIS Version 3.36 the expression is not working? 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CAtjN7rqstxlUkXZhq168nWAZHiROpor/view?usp=drive_link